# Which model shall be used by using() in django when there are two models with same name and different apps in the same db?

Tags: django, django-models, database-migration, objectquery

I have defined a model MyUser in two apps(let's say A and B) in different projects in django with the same DB(CAP_db). The second project uses more than one DB. So, when querying the model MyUser in one of its apps, I am using the statement : `ambassador = MyUser.objects.using('CAP_db').get(code=code)`.

By default, Django is creating the two tables a_myuser and b_myuser for the model from the two different apps. Is there any way to direct the query from one particular table( from the different project i.e. a_myuser)?

Note: The model doesn't contain any foreign key nor is used as a foreign key in any other model. Also, the views.py for the query doesn't import any models from any app.

Comment: This can be done  by using A.objects.raw() as you can do your own select

Comment: This way, won't the model not be accessible in the other project and the error A is not defined will be returned?